# Android synchronized two listviews that have different item height

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

I have two listview side by side that model a tv program schedule.
One of listview have only hours in it, each of the item(hour) have fixed height.
The other listview have shows that can last more than one hour, thus some row could have twice the height of the hours, which means it is 2 hours.

My question is, how can I synchronized the two listview so that they scroll the same amount of y position?